# Excel Formula. Determine how to distribute a negative amount to other positive amounts

Tags: math, excel-formula

Not sure if this is the right forum for an Excel Formula question but's a math and logic based one and figure programmers are more likely to solve it.

I have say $5,000 and I have 3 pots to put it in based on a % of each pot should get. But some of the pots are of a negative percent. 
Pot 1 = 14%
Pot 2 = -15%
Pot 3 = 1%

That's how much each pot should get of the $5k.

The problem is that because the second pot is negative it comes out with a negative $(647.48). This amount should be distributed to the other two pots. I guess 50/50.

I'm not sure how to logically write this out in Excel or what the math should be. I'm skimming through all the Excel Math formulas but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Type on cells A9, B9 and C9 respectively:

```
=(B3*B2)+IF(B4<0,((-B4*B2)/2),0)+IF(B5<0,((-B5*B2)/2),0)
=(B4*B2)+IF(B3<0,((-B3*B2)/2),0)+IF(B5<0,((-B5*B2)/2),0)
=(B5*B2)+IF(B3<0,((-B3*B2)/2),0)+IF(B4<0,((-B4*B2)/2),0)
```

Play with values on cells B3, B4 and B5 to see if it does what you need.

Comment: Awesome! I guess I could have thought about using If statements but seemed with 1,000 excel formulas I just thought there'd be one but this works great. Thanks.